# More secure encryption than AES to flash

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to store some "license data" securely and verify it from flash.
 The flash file is offline,  no client-server / calling home.

There is a nice AES class that can be easily ported to Actionscript.

http://aesencryption.net/#Java-aes-encryption-example

Is there somewhere similar asymmetric encryption (public+private key) algorithm available?

I dont want to include my secret key to the flash module itself, just the public key.

Comment: [Literally the first result on google for "aes as3"](https://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/)

Comment: I say download the key from elsewhere, or generate a key pair within your SWF. But, you'd better have a  client-server infrastructure, get a key pair on the server, embed public key to SWF, and send verification data to the server, encrypted by public key and receive a response. In order to make the response encrypted, you will have to generate a key pair in the SWF at runtime, and send the public key to the server

Comment: flash file is offline.

Comment: Be careful when/if using as3crypto. It is terribly slow... I didn't try to optimize it but our javascript tests were like 10x+ times faster.